# how to search other field in many2one?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

python code:

```
_name = 'res.partner.table2'

customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', required=True ,string="Customer ID")
```

XML:

```xml
<field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Reward Points">
            <field name="customer_id"/>  //how can i search by res.partner customer_id in here 
      </form>
</field>
```

I need search by other field instead "name". How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve with following:

```xml
<field name="customer_id" context="{'my_custom_search': True}"/>
```

We add context to make sure functionality will effect to particular field and not disturb existing functionality.

```py
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    def name_search(self, cr, uid, name, args=None, operator='ilike', context=None, limit=100):
        if not args:
            args = []
        if not context:
            context = {}
        if context.has_key('my_custom_search'):
            domain = [('field_name', 'operator', value)]
            ids = self.search(domain)
        else:
            return super(res_partner, self).name_search(cr, user, name, args=args, operator='ilike', context=context, limit=limit)
        return self.name_get(cr, uid, ids, context)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful to me！！

Answer (score 0):

If for example you want to search by a new field (`emp_code`) in the `hr.employee`, I would suggest something like:

```
    @api.model
    def _name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None):
        args = args or []
        domain = []
        if name:
            domain = ['|', ('emp_code', 'ilike', name), ('name', operator, name)]
            if operator in expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS:
                domain = ['&', '!'] + domain[1:]
        return self._search(expression.AND([domain, args]), limit=limit, access_rights_uid=name_get_uid)
```

The `expression.NEGATIVE_TERM_OPERATORS` will check for negative operators like `!=`.

This code was "inspired" by the one found at Odoo's `account/models/account_account.py` [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/e24295da8436b4d24cd03f6ac1f22e86465f950d/addons/account/models/account_account.py#L363).

Side note: all of Odoo's community version is inheriting from `_name_search` and not `name_search`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, I had to search through parent task in the task with id as well as name, this is how I did, I used name_search function to pass domain and use name_get to return the result. Hope it will be useful, good luck

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    args = args or []
    recs = self.browse()
    if not recs:
        recs = self.search(['|',('name', operator, name),('id', operator, name)] + args, limit=limit)
    return recs.name_get()
```